# How do I enable multi touch features on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have ASUS eee top touch screen computer.

Is there some place which I should visit to enable e.g. 2 fingers scrolling, or long tap for some extra actions, etc?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that TabletPC features are turned on. If you type `features` into the start menu, an option for `Turn Windows Features On and Off` should appear. Locate Tablet PC Components on that list, and check the box to enable them.

[image: windows touch features]

Then, download the [Microsoft Touch Pack for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b152fadd-82e4-4ddb-a46a-aebe49944428&displaylang=en) from the Microsoft Download Center. This will give you some extra touch applications like various games and tools.

Unfortunately, Windows 7 is not really designed as a touch-centric OS like the iPad. You will not have gestures for everything you might want, but should be able to use gestures in Internet Explorer to browse pages, and should be able to add in handwriting recognition, multitouch zooming, etc. with the tablet PC features.

Answer (score 1):

Multitouch would have to be supported first by the hardware, and next by its driver.

**If** the support is there, I'd expect you to find options to manipulate its behavior in the Control Panel, either as a custom tab in the 'Mouse' applet, or as a complete replacement for it in the form of a 'Touch' or 'Tablet' or 'Pen' kind of applet.

What model of device do you have?  Does Asus bill it as multitouch capable?

Comment: I have Asus EEE top it's a touch screen. There is a program which ships together with their drivers, which introduces some gestures, but they don't seem to work very reliable... I wonder if something like multitouch can work on W7.... Before that I've used iPad and everything worked out-of-the-box....

Comment: @Oleg - just because it's a touchscreen doesn't mean it does multitouch.  Not all touch devices can do it. iPad can, but your eee might not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Windows 7 Home or higher installed on your netbook. Windows 7 Starter doesn't support Windows Touch ([Windows 7 different editions comparation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/compare?T1=tab02))